# WPF/Console Hybrid application quit

Tags: c#, wpf, hybrid

I am trying to create a WPF - hybrid application. This application should have the option to be started from command prompt, where in this case, it would not show any window but will only start some process and then quit.

For example (made up example) in my WPF application I enable users to create body of an email message that will be send to any user (sort of a template).
Afterwards when user wants to send the email, he can do it via cmd like following (meaning GUI will not even start, it will only call email connector and send message to selected recipient and then quit program):

```
MyProgram.exe -recipient john@doe.com -send=true
```

My Main() looks like this (created based on the following website:http://www.jankowskimichal.pl/en/2011/12/wpf-hybrid-application-with-parameters/)

```
public static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool AllocConsole();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool FreeConsole();

        [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int lpdwProcessId);

        [STAThreadAttribute]
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //App.Main();

            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                IP_DynamicMailings.App app = new IP_DynamicMailings.App();
                app.InitializeComponent();
                app.Run();
            }
            else
            {
                // Get uppermost window process
                IntPtr ptr = GetForegroundWindow();
                int u;
                GetWindowThreadProcessId(ptr, out u);
                Process process = Process.GetProcessById(u);

                // Check if it is console?
                if (process.ProcessName == "cmd")
                {
                    // Yes – attach to active console
                    AttachConsole(process.Id);
                }
                else
                {
                    // No – create new console
                    AllocConsole();
                }

                // Program actions ...


                foreach (var item in args)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                }

                FreeConsole();
            }
        }
    }
```

What happens is, that I need to press Enter in order to quit application.
I am also open to rewrite my hybrid logic, shall you have better solution (this was so far the best I could find).

Comment: What is the actual question, and what problems are you facing?

Comment: I need to press Enter in order to quit application. How is that possible?

Comment: @RobertJ.: I might be missing something, but wouldn't `Console.ReadLine();` before `FreeConsole()` work here?

Comment: Console.ReadLine() would cause program to wait for key input...that is what I am trying to avoid

Comment: @RobertJ.: Still confused. DOes your current solution require enter in order to quit, and you want to get rid of that? If not, then `Console.ReadLine()` would wait as long as you press enter.

Comment: I want to be able to execute my application from command prompt by passing arguments. Once the process has completed, it will quit the application without showing GUI.